# How can I optimize the parameters in a function where the y-variable is not isolatable?

Tags: r, optimization, parameters

I have defined the following function in R:

```
# Equilibrium precipitation isotherm model
fun <- function(z, k, n, b0, b1, b2, coa, cp0){
  q <- z
  eq1 <- q^(1+n*(b0*exp(b1*coa+b2*cp0)))-k*coa*(cp0-q)^n
  return(eq1)
}
```

Where the function is written in a way so that it is equal to zero. k, n, b0, b1, b2 are the parameters that i want to optimize, coa is my x variable, cp0 is a constant and q is my y variable.

Right now I am able to obtain values for q by setting an initial guess for q, guessing values for the parameters by hand and then using nleqslv:

```
# Initial guess for q
q0 <- rep(1e-6,100)
q0l <- rep(1,99)

# Parameters
k <- 8e8
n <- 2.6
b0 <- 0.8e-2
b1 <- 2.3e2
b2 <- 0.5e4

#Numerically evaluate q using the equilibrium precipitation isotherm model
q_mod1 <- nleqslv(q0, fun, coa=coa, k=k, n=n, b0=b0, b1=b1, b2=b2, cp0=cp01)
q_mod2 <- nleqslv(q0, fun, coa=coa, k=k, n=n, b0=b0, b1=b1, b2=b2, cp0=cp02)
q_mod3 <- nleqslv(q0, fun, coa=coa, k=k, n=n, b0=b0, b1=b1, b2=b2, cp0=cp03)
q_mod4 <- nleqslv(q0, fun, coa=coa, k=k, n=n, b0=b0, b1=b1, b2=b2, cp0=cp04)
q_mod5 <- nleqslv(q0, fun, coa=coa, k=k, n=n, b0=b0, b1=b1, b2=b2, cp0=cp05)
```

The modeled values of are then plotted as follows:

```
#Plot
plot(coa1, q1, 
     ylim = c(0,5e-5), 
     xlab = "OA concentration [mol/L]",
     ylab = "Precipitate concentration [mol/L]",
     title("Albumin Precipitated vs OA Conc. (Buffered in 0.22 M NaAc pH 4.4)"))
grid()
lines(coa1,q1)
lines(coa, q_mod1$x, col="red")
points(coa2, q2)
lines(coa2,q2)
lines(coa, q_mod2$x, col="red")
points(coa3, q3)
lines(coa3,q3)
lines(coa, q_mod3$x, col="red")
points(coa4, q4)
lines(coa4,q4)
lines(coa, q_mod4$x, col="red")
points(coa5, q5)
lines(coa5,q5)
lines(coa, q_mod5$x, col="red")
```

Where q1 to q5 are the values for q that were determined experimentally and q_mod1$x to q_mod1$x are the values obtained from the model.

My question now is, if there is a way to optimize the parameters alongside with the y-variable.

My initial attempt was to calculate the residuals between the q values I obtained experimentally and the q values modeled and then optimizing the parameters by minimizing the square of the residuals. However, I cannot isolate q in my function which is why I have set up the equation as equal to zero in my current approach. I feel that if I try the residuals approach, I need to optimize both the parameters and q simultaneously which I am not quite sure how to approach.